# Where do you find the file lists that Microsoft collects from your system?

Tags: windows, services, anti-virus, privacy, privacy-protection

System ->

Update & Security ->

Windows security (on the left) ->

Virus & threat protection (on the right) ->

Manage settings (under Virus & threat protection settings on the right)

You'll find "Cloud-delivered protection" and "Automatic sample submission" here.

They are defined as "Provides increased and faster protection with access to the latest protection data in the cloud. Works best with Automatic sample submission turned on" and "Send sample files to Microsoft to help protect you and others from potential threats. We'll prompt you if the file we need is likely to contain personal information".

Clearly there is a benefit to these services. I've seen the example made where it "sampled" a strange file, uploaded it, found that it was a virus, removed it from ones system, then created a virus definition for other users, all in a matter of 8 seconds. Impressive if true.

I just want to know what Microsoft considers "potential threats", so I know how much of my privacy I'm spending to pay for this service.

Comment: You probably won't be able to find a definite definition as that would be attackers could craft their threats to be not recognized as such. Usually it means files that could potentially include executable code.

Comment: So is it a blank cheque for Microsoft to grab whatever they want?

Comment: I'm sorry, but "go use something else" is hardly productive wording in this discussion of privacy disclosure. It sounds like your answer to the question would be that "it is not publicly available", though, it sounds like you're basing this off of how you feel rather than fact. I'll defer to the original question of, What am I paying for this virus protection?

Comment: You already seem to mistrust Microsoft a good deal. As such you will not be satisfied. Most if not all other cloud AV solutions have the same blanket statement. This is due to the number of different threats and the varying attack surface of each individual machine in addition to marketing reasons and so on. You find a conclusive list of file extensions or exact criteria what defines a threat. A common approach is to have a check against a hash and if a file hash isn't known and it's deemed a potential threat it's uploaded. Sometimes just meta data, sometimes the whole file.